# URL Presigned AMZON S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, bucket, pre-signed-url

I'm not able to make url Presigned to my subdomain pointed to my bucket,

URL AMAZON - /mybucket/logo.jpg

OR

MY SUBDOMAIN - / logo.jpg

Works correctly

But when file is private, I need to generate permission, so it would look like this, but when I put the access key in the subdomain it does not work.

[URL ORIGINAL AMAZON](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/teste.darpine.com/cover.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ6ZIUP5DMPVU2RJQ%2F20170714%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170714T010819Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=36000&X-Amz-Signature=4aa4ceccfcc0b368672219adb811bdd809e971fa18057b4381f5b67fbe9e9b30)

[SUBDOMAIN + KEY, DOES NOT WORK](http://teste.darpine.com/cover.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ6ZIUP5DMPVU2RJQ%2F20170714%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170714T010819Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=36000&X-Amz-Signature=4aa4ceccfcc0b368672219adb811bdd809e971fa18057b4381f5b67fbe9e9b30)

my php code

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'teste.darpine.com',
    'Key'    => 'cover.jpg'
]);
$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+10 hours');
echo $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Someone please introduce me a light.

Comment: Side-comment: I experimented with the `aws s3 presign` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It generates a different (older) version of pre-signed URLs, but it successfully worked with both formats of URLs: `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/...` and `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/...`.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093081/problems-with-amazon-s3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092709/get-url-presigned-of-object-private-for-static-website-hosting  Please do not ask the same question more than once.